# Url image to imageview

Tags: java, android

```
    ImageView imgview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
    Drawable drawable = LoadImage("http://192.168.172.1/myproject/images/st1.jpg");
    imgview.setImageDrawable(drawable);
    ...
    ...
public Drawable LoadImage(String url)
{

    try
    {
        InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
        Drawable b = Drawable.createFromStream(is, url);
    return b;
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
        return null;
    }

}
```

.java

```
     ...
     ...
     <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
```

.xml

getting the image from wamp server as a Url and display it onto my xml but image doesn't shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you given internet permission on manifest

and running this code in background such as asyn task

```
 class LoadImageLoader extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         drawable = LoadImage("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png");
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        imgview.setImageDrawable(drawable);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I use the following `code` to get an `image` from `url` and add it to an `ImageView`:

```
ImageRequest imgRequest = new ImageRequest(url,
            new Response.Listener<Bitmap>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Bitmap response) {
                    mImageView.setImageBitmap(response);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Succes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }, 0, 0, ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mImageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

    Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(imgRequest);
```

All you need to do is to use `Volley Library` made by `google developers`(trusted source). More info [here](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html)

Hope it helps!

Comment: This is better than the accepted answer. Would have been perfect if you had suggested NetworkImageView instead.

Comment: @e4c5 Thanks for your feedback! I never used NetworkImageView before, but after I have read about, it sounds like a good idea combined with ImageLoader.

Answer (score 1):

Use http://square.github.io/picasso/ it's really easy to implement, follow the following steps:-

1- If you haven’t done it already. If you are using eclipse as your development IDE, then just copy the downloaded picasso-2.5.2.jar file into your application lib folder. If you are using Android Studio IDE, then you have to add below dependency in build.gradle file.

```
dependencies {
 ...
 compile "com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2"
 ...
 }
```

2- Now let us download the image and display on imageView:-

```
//Loading image from below url into imageView

Picasso.with(this)
.load("YOUR IMAGE URL HERE")
.into(imageView);//Your image view
```

That's all, Hope this will help you !!

Answer (score 0):

Use [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso) works great and is easy to use.

Comment: hmm don't really like to use third-party as there might be some configuration to made.

Answer (score 0):

There are many third party libraries that can help you with that.
Their use is strongly recommended, ie. don't create your own tool for that.

- [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) by guys from Square
- [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) used in sample apps by Google